# vueJs routing components adds resolve: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I added dynamic components to the route。

```
component: resolve => require([`${item.component}`], resolve)
```

Console warning：
[image]

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

If I delete, it does not appear

```
component: resolve => require([`${item.component}`], resolve)
```

But that is not what I want, I do not want this warning

Comment: Please copy&paste the warning to the post instead of showing in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
component: resolve => require([`${item.component}.vue`], resolve)
```

String variables are spliced into a string. But there's no problem with a single page entrance.

Comment: codeRabbit, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).